# while submiting login button nothing happens in my webpage

Tags: html, django

my HTML is

```
<form method="POST" action="{% url 'lawyerdash' %}">
    {% csrf_token %}
    username<input type="text" name="username"><br>
    password<input type="password" name="password" ><br>

    <input type="button" value="sign in" >
```

my view is

```
  def lawyerdash(request):
        if request.method == 'POST':
            if Lawyer.objects.filter(username=request.POST['username'], password=request.POST['password']).exists():
                lawyer = Lawyer.objects.get(username=request.POST['username'], password=request.POST['password'])

                return render(request, 'lawyerpage.html', {'lawyer': lawyer})
      else:
          return HttpResponse("<h1>Not found.........</h2>")
```

my URL is

```
url(r'^lawyerdash/$',views.lawyerdash,name="lawyerdash"),
```

after clicking sign in it should go to the following page(lawyerpage.html)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>welcome {{lawyer.name}}</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you try  @Rick Colgan answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should use `<input type="submit">Sign In</input>` Instead of type button

Comment: Nice. Then please consider as answer

Answer (score 2):

```
<input type='submit'>Sign In</input>
```

is what you really need. The "button" type is fine for links and such because it is just a clickable button. The "reset" type will reset the form on your page to its initial values. The "submit" type will submit your form data.